# Android Webview net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Error To Play Store

Tags: android, android-webview

I have problem Android webview App, When I click a link to google play which goes to Play Store App,  I get this error:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

[error image ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHBJG.jpg)

This is my MainActivity.java full: https://date.perjaka.id/android-webview-neterr_unknown_url_scheme-error-to-play-store.html

Please Help me :(
i'm frustated this problem for my project.

```
package id.ayogoonline.www.forumpencarianjodohonline;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebView webView;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath = null;
    private long size = 0;

    // Storage Permissions variables
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        try {
            String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:","");
            File file = new File(file_path);
            size = file.length();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
            Integer count = 0; //fix fby https://github.com/nnian
            ClipData images = null;
            try {
                images = data.getClipData();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) {
                count = data.getDataString().length();
            } else if (images != null) {
                count = images.getItemCount();
            }
            Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (size != 0) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    }
                }
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have read or write permission
        int writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int cameraPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        verifyStoragePermissions(this);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
        //if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration otherwise activate software acceleration
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.ayogoonline.id/");
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // For Android 5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUploadMessage = filePath;
            Log.e("FileCooserParams => ", filePath.toString());

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[2];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, "Select images"), 1);

            return true;

        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public class PQClient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
            if (url.contains("mailto:")) {

                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                // Here we can open new activity

                return true;

            } else {

                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                    "document.getElementById('android-app').style.display='none';})()");

            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: thank you for your advice, I deleted it.
Hello  @karan I am a newbie in the Android studio, I still do not understand where the codes are placed.

Comment: Check the answer below @JumadilAwal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is appeared because the WebView can’t recognize the special URL Scheme,

for example, the WebView will usually recognize http and https, anything other than these, for example – intent://, market://, app://, mail:// , whatsapp:// etc will not be recognized by WebView unless we add a handler to handle these url schemes, or by disabling these schemes and only load http and https schemes.

The Code to Fix err_unknown_url_scheme intent://

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               String currentUrl;

               @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                   currentUrl = url;

                   if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
                       return false;
                   }
                   if (url.startsWith("intent")) {

                     try {
                         Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);

                         String fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra("browser_fallback_url");
                       if (fallbackUrl != null) {
                           webview.loadUrl(fallbackUrl);
                           return true;
                       }}
                   catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                       //not an intent uri
                   }
           return true;//do nothing in other cases
    }
```

Comment: For more reference read this blog - https://www.zidsworld.com/android-development/how-to-fix-unknown-url-scheme-in-android-webview/

Comment: thanks ravi, this is work

Comment: Thanks man! This saved my day.

Comment: @MonimKaiser WC