# how to add whatsap and telegram Android Webview ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have problem Android webview App, When I click a link to whatsapp and tellegram , I get this error: `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error image `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. This is my `MainActivity.java` full

my main activity java code is this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }
    @Override

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

What do I need to add to this code? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402339/680091

Looks like you need to separately handle these types of links because webview does not know how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code under shouldovrrideurlLoading in webviewclient Must install telegram before running this code

```
            if (url.startsWith("tg:")) {
       
                Intent telegramIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
                telegramIntent.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");

                try {
                    startActivity(telegramIntent);
                    return true;

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                    // Telegram app not installed, open in browser

                    webView.loadUrl("https://telegram.org/");

                    return true;
                }
            }
```